# Where can I find the Conversational Profile Link when integrating Dialogflow CX with Voximplant?

Tags: dialogflow-cx, voximplant

Currently I integrated an agent of Dialgoflow CX with Voximplant. I am having trouble adding an EventListener with CCAI.Conversation. It seems that I need to add the conversational profile link of Dialogflow CX, but I'm not sure where to find it.

```
agent.addEventListener(CCAI.Events.Agent.Started, () => {
    conversation = new CCAI.Conversation({ agent, profile: { name: profile }, project: appName });
    conversation.addEventListener(CCAI.Events.Conversation.Created, () => {
      isConversationCreated = true;
      createParticipant();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to integrate Voximplant with Dialogflow CX is using [one-click integration](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/integrations/dialogflowcx), and in this case conversation profile is created automatically and is put into the scenario code, so you shouldn't need to create conversation profile and corresponding part of scenario manually.